Does a p-paginator inside a p-table communicate the same or differently to a p-paginator outside the p-table?
I'm asking this question because I recently worked on a project and small part of that project was adding pagination(comes from PrimeNG) to both the top and bottom of the page where the data was laid out for easy accessibility to different pages.
The problem I was having was that there was already pagination outside the p-table and they wanted a paginator inside the p-table in a certain placement. I did a lot of testing with it and was unable to get a result with using a paginator inside and outside the table. I was able to get the paginator inside the p-table to communicate it's changes to the page and rows elements of the outside paginator but whatever changes I made on the outside paginator would never reflect on the inside paginator.
Here is the options we used for that p-table for context and I'll place the value of variables above it:
defaultRecordsCountPerPage= 50; //This is how many rows to display per page
totalRecordsCount= 0; //This is what record # were on per page so if we got to page 2 on paginator it would show totalRecordsCount = 50; basically adding 50 each time it changed pages.
predefinedRecordsCountPerPage= [5, 10, 25, 50]; //Options for number of rows per page
<p-table
  #dataTable
  (onLazyLoad)="getData($event)"
  [value]="primengTableHelper.records"
  [paginator]="false"
  [rows]="primengTableHelper.defaultRecordsCountPerPage"
  [lazy]="true"
  [scrollable]="false"
  selectionMode="single"
>
 <p-paginator
   [rows]="primengTableHelper.defaultRecordsCountPerPage"
   #paginator
   (onPageChange)="getData($event)"
   [totalRecords]="primengTableHelper.totalRecordsCount"
   [rowsPerPageOptions]="primengTableHelper.predefinedRecordsCountPerPage"
 >
 </p-paginator>
</p-table>
<p-paginator
  [rows]="primengTableHelper.defaultRecordsCountPerPage"
  #paginator
  (onPageChange)="getData($event)"
  [totalRecords]="primengTableHelper.totalRecordsCount"
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="primengTableHelper.predefinedRecordsCountPerPage"
>
 </p-paginator>

(Update)I forgot to include some information on getData($event), this had what it was sending to the paginators. It had things like those below in it as a base template for what I was testing things out with as well as to read the variables it was giving.
getData(event?: LazyLoadEvent){
  this.paginator.rows = event.rows;
  this.paginator._first = event.first;
  this.paginator._page = event.page;
  this.PrimengTableHelper.defaultRecordsCountPerPage = event. rows;
  this.PrimengTableHelper.totalRecordsCount = event._first;
}

I tried a number of things such as changing variables of the @ViewChild('paginator', { static: true }) paginator: Paginator; so that the variables used by both paginators would always be the same but after numerous attempts at getting it to work and watching network connections, searching the elements, and reading that state of event in debug, I was unable to figure out where my problem was coming from.
I eventually figured out a different method which was to remove both p-paginator's from the html and setup the settings for paginator of p-table as it has components for adding a paginator to both the top and bottom of the p-table even though it doesn't have many options for placement it just so happened to coincide with how we wanted the paginators to look on the p-table to begin with.
Even though I did figure out the method of adding the paginator through p-table, I'm still curious why the original method failed. Please let me know if you figured it out or need more information from me!
